# Significato di "a spina di pesce" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Erano vicini alla chiesa e gli parve di cogliere un trepestío, gente che scappa a nascondersi in punta di piedi. Milton col mento accennò di sí a Hombre che con gli occhi gli domandava se avesse sentito pure lui. «In chiesa», bisbigliò Hombre ed entrarono con ogni precauzione. C’era ombra e fresco. Cominciarono col frugare nel battistero, quindi nel primo confessionale. Non si sentiva un alito. Hombre sbirciò su alla cantoria ma poi scacciò l’idea e si diede a perquisire i banchi uno dopo l’altro. Cosí, **a spina di pesce**, si avvicinavano all’altare maggiore. Si avvicinavano e da dietro l’altare sbuca un soldato con le mani alzate e dice: «Siamo qui dietro», con una voce da fanciulla.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "a spina di pesce" in questo passaggio? Alla voce "spina" di diversi dizionari ho trovato che questa locuzione si usa per qualificare qualcosa che ha una disposizione simile a una liscia di pesce, ma non riesco a capirne il senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato.

Answer (score 1):

Nel contesto da te citato avvicinarsi a spina di pesce vuol dire che procedevano verso l’altare mantenendo una disposizione a spina di pesce, cioè chi stava al centro era coperto (nel senso che era difeso) da coloro che stavano ai lati.

Immagina un triangolo in cui le persone stanno ai vertici e procedono in avanti.

Answer (score 1):

Immagino che i banchi fossero “all’antica”, del tipo simile a questo

[image: banco]

Impossibile quindi escludere la presenza di qualcuno nascosto senza esaminare tutte le file di banchi. Quindi Hombre e gli altri decisero di procedere una fila alla volta: centro, fila di destra e fila di sinistra fino al lato, poi dal lato verso il centro sulla fila successiva. E così via, seguendo un percorso che assomiglia a seguire i bordi di una lisca.

Answer (score 0):

Alla [voce "pesce" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00171.jpg) si trova la definizione della locuzione "a spina di pesce" con valore avverbiale e, come esempio, si cita  precisamente il passo di Fenoglio che appare nella domanda.

Nel testo l'espressione fa riferimento al modo in cui questi partigiani si muovevano nella chiesa, avanzando verso l'altare, disposti in modo obliquo rispetto a un asse centrale (non so bene se delineato da una fila di uomini, come suggerito da abarisone, o da qualche altro oggetto):

> – Con valore avverb.    Dipartendosi  radialmen­te e più o meno obliquamente da un asse   centrale (con riferimento a un movimento o  a   una disposi­zione). 
>       *G. Raimondi*, 1-178:  Un  pavimento  di  mattoni  rossi.  I mattoni  sono  commessi  a  ‘resca  di  pesce’.  Ricorda  il  fondo di  una  nave. 
>   *Moravia*, 25-153:  Dal  casamento,  il  mio sguardo  retrocede  alle  macchine  parcheggiate  a  spina  di pesce  lungo  il  marciapiede. *Fenoglio*, 1-241:  Cominciarono col  frugare  nel  battistero,  quindi  nel  primo  confessiona­le...  Così,  a  spina  di  pesce,  si avvicinavano  all’altare maggiore.